# How can I know how many matches get replaced in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

Let's say I have a function that looks like this:

```
function countReplacements ( string, search, replacement ) {
    string.replace ( search, replacement );
}
```

What's the cleanest, and most reliable, way of knowing how many matches get replaced into the string?

I've thought of the following possible solutions:

- Wrap the `replacement` value with a Proxy that logs every time its proxied value gets accessed. This isn't transpilable down to older versions of JS though.
- Reimplement the algorithm used in `String.prototype.replace` so that every time it replaces something it logs this. This isn't very clean at all.
- If `search` is a string or a non-global regex I can check if `string` includes/matches it. But if `search` is a global regex, when JS will have support for lookbehinds I'm not sure this will work, maybe all matches are computed before actually replacing them? If this isn't the case any replacement may cause the following lookbehinds to no longer match, or to now match things that it wouldn't have matched in the original string.

What do you think is the best solution to the problem?

Comment: @Thomas that's why I said "when JS _will_ have support for lookbehinds", they will probably become part of the language in ES2018.

Comment: If your `search` is a RegExp, has the `global` flag set and contains lookbehinds, then convert it into a new RegExp without the global flag, and replace in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plain cases when the replacement is a string, for the second argument to `.replace`, use a callback function rather than the plain `replacement` string, and have the callback increment a variable:

```js
function countReplacements(string, search, replacement) {
  let count = 0;
  const result = string.replace(search, () => {
    count++;
    return replacement;
  });
  return { count, result };
}

console.log(countReplacements('foobar', /o/g, 'a'));
```

For the more complicated cases when `replacement` is a function or a string containing group references, you'll either have to re-implement `String.prototype.replace` on your own: use the parameters provided to `.replace` to get the full match and the groups:

```js
function countReplacements(string, search, replacement) {
  let count = 0;
  const result = string.replace(search, (match, ...groups) => {
    count++;
    return replacement
      .replace(/\$(\d+|&)/g, (_, indicator) => {
        if (indicator === '&') return match;
        if (/^\d+$/.test(indicator)) return groups[indicator - 1];
        // and so on for other `$`s
      });
  });
  return { count, result };
}

console.log(countReplacements ( 'foobar', /(o)/g, '$1_' ));
```

A much lazier but easier to implement version would just be to call `match` and check the `length` of the result, though this will require going through the string with the regex *twice*:

```js
function countReplacements(string, search, replacement) {
  const match = string.match(search);
  const count = match ? match.length : 0;
  const result = string.replace(search, replacement);
  return { count, result };
}

console.log(countReplacements ( 'foobar', /(o)/g, '$1_' ));
```

> If search is a string or a non-global regex I can check if string includes/matches it. But if search is a global regex, when JS will have support for lookbehinds I'm not sure this will work, maybe all matches are computed before actually replacing them? If this isn't the case any replacement may cause the following lookbehinds to no longer match, or to now match things that it wouldn't have matched in the original string.

This won't be a problem - the only issue with using `.match` to get the count in addition to `.replace` is that it requires going through the string twice. The string's replacements are all calculated at once, where the lookarounds are looking at the *original string*. Then, once all matches are found and the replacements are calculated, each matched substring is replaced with its replacement.

Comment: This doesn't work for all possible values that can get passed as `search` and `replacement`, for instance this won't work: `countReplacements ( 'foobar', /(o)/g, '$1_' )`

Comment: Also maybe `replacement` is a function, it doesn't make sense to just return a function there, we should return a string from the wrapper arrow function you wrote.

Comment: @FabioSpampinato The callback function needs to implement everything that the standard `replace()` function does: replacing all the `$n` with the capture groups, or calling `replacement` if it's a function. But the general structure to do the counting is the same.

Comment: That's one of my proposed solutions then, which as I said it's not very clean. I'm looking for a better solution to this.